# Example for using ROS2 Moveit2's asyncExecute()

Tags: ros2, moveit, motion-planning, ros-humble, rclcpp

I would like to use the [`asyncExecute()`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L1462) function offered by Moveit2 CPP API (ROS2 Humble), and then monitor the status of execution.

I searched for a bit and only found some [old answers](https://answers.ros.org/question/249995/how-to-check-sate-of-plan-execution-in-moveit-during-async-execution-in-python/) that say this is not even possible. Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L784) it seems that the execution status is not exposed through the API in any way.

My question is - is it still not possible to monitor execution in anyway through the API, or has anyone figured out a way?

If it is not possible, what other approaches could be taken?

Option1: My fallback idea was to actually monitor the current pose of the robot and when it stops changing for a while, say execution is done. Using Eigen should even be a fairly optimized calculation. While checking this, I am free to do other things in the loop, which satisfies my need for asynchronicity.

Option2: The above old answer also suggested to monitor the feedback topic directly. In ROS2, this is still discoverable through `ros2 topic list --include-hidden-topics` and the `/execute_trajectory/_action/feedback` topic seems to give the info I need. But as was stated in another thread (sorry no link), this is pretty ugly and prone to breakage.

Opinions on which option might be better?